# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not HTTPResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on getting a basis on how to write a password generator for a final project in my programming class.  The area of code that's currently giving me problems looks like:

```
`if not isfile('words.txt'):
    print('Downloading words.txt ...')
    url=str('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt')
    with open('words.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(urlopen(url)).read()`
```

With the help of a friend, we decided to 'brute force' url to have str().  The error message I get implies that I need to put write() into str() but in doing that I get an error about,

> 'io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'str'

.  This was originally written in Python 2, however, I managed to get everything working in Python 3.8.0 excluding the block of code above.  Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: It looks like it should be `f.write(urlopen(url).read())`, you want to read in the contents of the url, not read `f`.

Comment: @Marius: Given `f.write()` returns either an `int` or `None`, not the stream it was called on, you couldn't read `f` that way anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlopen` returns a httpresponse object, not a string. You can only write strings or bytes to a file- not an arbitrary object. You use that object like so (read() returns bytes- if you want a string, have to decode it)

```
with urlopen(url) as resp:
  print(resp.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

So, to get your code working do-

```
with open('words.txt', 'w') as f:
    with urlopen(url) as resp:
        f.write(resp.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
f.write(urlopen(url)).read()
```

You are trying to read the file **f**

Try using

```
f.write(urlopen(url).read())
```